# Create a engine to replace template entries with json objects in python

Tags: python, json, template-engine

I want to create an engine in python that can replace tags in a template file with objects from json? I've loooked at python based engines that use regex but they are overly complicated and  I am a little confused as to how to start an go about it. Any code to start would help

Sample json file

```
{
  "webbpage": {
    "title": "Stackoverflow"
  },
  "Songs": {
    "name": "Mr Crowley"
  },
  "CoverArtists": [
    { "name": "Ozzy", "nicknames": ["Ozzman","Ozzster"] },
    { "name": "Slipknot", "nicknames": ["Slip"] }
  ]
}
```

Sample template file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%% webbpage.title %%></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%% Songs.name %%></h1>
    <%% EACH CoverArtists artist %%>
      <%% artist.name %%>
      <%% EACH CoverArtists.nicknames nickname %%>
        <p><%% nickname %%></p>
      <%% END %%>
    <%% END %%>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically variables are identified between <%% and %%> and loops are identifed between <%% EACH .. %%> AND <%% END %%> and basically output html

Comment: Why not use an existing engine such as [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)?  Also, wouldn't it make more sense to use python data structures if you're writing it in python?

Comment: im trying to learn templating and I need to write it myself to learn the nitty gritties of templating and regular expression concepts.:) COuld you please elaborate on using python data structure. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Alex Mitchells [blog](https://github.com/alexmic/microtemplates) on templating (python based), it's extremely helpful, and the related GIT [here](https://github.com/alexmic/microtemplates)

Basically,

1. Take input files on command line
2. Parse template file - build Abstract Syntax tree to parse easily. Create a node base type, and then for each new type implement a concrete class
3. Build stack to keep track of loops, pop when loops close, look for errors of missing loop ends
4. Parse json file, build dictionary of objects, map AST entries and replace in html
5. Write output to file.

I have a version of this based on Alex mitchells engine [here](https://github.com/vrash/PythonTemplateEngine), where I've fixed some issues with the original one( and put it in some code of my own) and  will be trying to get rid of the reg exp based matching and put in contextual matching, because regular expressions dont work too well on large complex HTML data.

Answer (score 2):

So basically you need to identify tokens within `<%%` and `%%>`.  This step can be done with a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), e.g. :

```
>>> import re
>>> t='<h1><%% Songs.name %%></h1>'
>>> re.search(r'<%%(.+?)%%>', t).groups()
(' Songs.name ',)
```

Parsing the code that this gives is quite a complicated task, and you might find some help in [shlex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) or [tokenizer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html).  Even if you need to use regular expressions for the entire project, I suggest you take a look at these, and examples from other languages, to understand how a syntax parser works.

Once you've parsed the language, the next step is to replace the tokens with values from json.  The best way would be to first load the data into python dicts, and then write a renderer to insert the data into the html.

Even if you can't use them, you should still have a look at some templating engines such as [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) or [chameleon](http://chameleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and study their source code to get an idea of how such a project is put together.